# Unable to click on more option list in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9, uitabbaritem

I have created a tabbar application with 6 tabs. 4 tabs and 1 "more" tab are showing when app launch. and its expected. 2 tab will show when user will click on more option.  When I clicked on more option, I am seeing list of 2 tab controllers. When I am selecting the a tab , nothing happened. It should be redirected to respective view controllers.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685411/2111223

Comment: I have setup with storyboard only, written below code for more option page customisation., When I removed this code , then also facing same issue.

Comment: I think this might be missing an [mcve]. Can you expand on it a bit, perhaps with code, or error logs?

Answer (score 1):

```
    let moreview = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView

    moreview?.tintColor = UIColor.darkText
    moreview?.tableFooterView = UIView()
    let headerView: UIView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (moreview?.frame.width)!, height: 44)
    moreview?.tableHeaderView = headerView
    moreview?.bounces = false
    if moreview?.subviews.count != nil {
        for cell: UITableViewCell? in moreview?.visibleCells ?? [UITableViewCell?]() {
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
```